# Duplicate NSString in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring

Would using

```
NSString* Test=[NSString stringWithString:@"Words"];
```

have any advantages over

```
NSString* Test=@"Words";
```

or is it just redundant?

Comment: No.  An NSString is immutable, so making a copy serves no purpose (other than to chew up time/space).  Likewise, the ever-popular `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]` is a waste of time, assuming that `someString` is an (immutable) NSString.  And one I saw earlier today, `[NSString stringWithFormat:someString]`, is downright dangerous, since `someString` may contain `%` characters.

Answer (score 2):

It's redundant.  `NSString` objects are immutable (cannot be changed) so there is no advantage that I can see over using the literal directly.

If you did the following, however:

```
NSMutableString *test = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Words"];
```

Then that's a different story.

Comment: Of course, for your "different story" `[@"Words" mutableCopy]` is more concise and the intention is clearer.

Comment: @HotLicks But further away from the OP's own example code...

Answer (score 1):

Any modern ObjC compiler will warn you if you try to instantiate a string like this...

> Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant

Use `@"literals"` unless you actually need to "operate" on the input, á la...

```
NSString * w = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Words"];
```

or

```
NSString * join = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"con%@enate", @"cat"]
```